# D-Link IP Camera viewer showing a black screen

Tags: ip-camera

My D-Link IP Camera that I've set up in Thailand to watch over an elderly relative doesn't seem to work at all.  When accessing the viewer from D-Link's page, I am greeted with a blank black screen, even in the proper light conditions.

However, checking with another relative who has assisted me by setting up the cameras in Thailand and he has no issues looking through the camera. So I've suspected the issue to be related to a firewall setting of some sort but I'm not quite sure where to look.

Where should I start to look to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What's the camera? What's the software? How are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of IP cam do you have and what is the name of the software you use? Without any of these information it's pretty difficult to help you.

What you can try:

1. Check the request-response communication to check that the connection have been established. You can use wireshark to check the HTTP/RTSP/RTP. If the connection is OK then listen for the RTP packets with the same program.
2. Try another client program to connect to your camera or create your own. You can find many of these on the internet like the [Onvif IP Camera Manager](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_27-onvif-ip-camera-manger-exe-demo-onvif.html). Try the trial version and if you can connect with this software then the problem is in your software not in the camera.
3. Create your own basic IP camera viewer program. You can use the [.NET SDK](http://www.camera-sdk.com) of the company what I linked before. Something like this:

   ```
   private IIPCamera _camera;
   private DrawingImageProvider _imageProvider = new DrawingImageProvider();
   private MediaConnector _connector = new MediaConnector();
   private VideoViewerWF _videoViewerWF1;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       // Create video viewer UI control
       _videoViewerWF1 = new VideoViewerWF();
       _videoViewerWF1.Name = "videoViewerWF1";
       _videoViewerWF1.Size = panel1.Size;
       panel1.Controls.Add(_videoViewerWF1);

       // Bind the camera image to the UI control
       _videoViewerWF1.SetImageProvider(_imageProvider);
   }

   // Connect camera video channel to image provider and start
   private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _camera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera("192.168.115.175:8080", "admin", "admin");
       _connector.Connect(_camera.VideoChannel, _imageProvider);
       _camera.Start();
       _videoViewerWF1.Start();
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you!